# unbale to send mails to distribution list with attachment unix/solaris 10

Tags: unix, solaris-10, mailx

trying to send mail to distribution list with attachment, but no luck

seems unbale to identified DL, but when specified with mail ids  (e.g. "xzy@eee.com,abc@eee.com") it works fine.

I have Oracle Solaris 10.

code be like..

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

mailx -s "test_mail" -r xyz@gmail.com -t "DL-xzy@outlook.com" < text_file.txt
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

uuencode text_file.txt text_file.txt| mailx -s " test mail" -t "DL-xzy@outlook.com"
```

result

```
Ignoring recipients on command line with -t
No recipients specified
```

OR
when using "mail" option

```
mail  -t "DL-xzy@outlook.com" -s "test_mail" -r xyz@gmail.com < text_file.txt
```

result:-

```
mail: Options MUST PRECEDE persons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command:

```
uuencode text_file.txt text_file.txt| mailx -s " test mail"  "DL-xzy@outlook.com"
```

DL as such is managed by mail server, `-t` have totally different role